# How do I write a function that removes duplicate customers from a database while adding the customer column sales? Keeping customers unique with sales

Tags: python, pandas, duplicates

I have a customer database, because of confidentiality cannot share it, but here is an example of it:

| ID | Name | Sales | Email | Etc |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | Pablo | $1000 | pablo@pablo.com | ------ |
| 02 | Pablo | $1000 | pablo@pablo.com | ------ |
| 03 | John | $1000 | john@john.com | ------ |
| 04 | Edward | $1000 | edward@edward.com | ------ |
| 05 | John | $1000 | john@john.com | ------ |

And what I am looking for is a function, with an output that looks like this, using duplicate emails :

| ID | Name | Sales | Email | Etc |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | Pablo | $2000 | pablo@pablo.com | ------ |
| 02 | John | $2000 | john@john.com | ------ |
| 03 | Edward | $1000 | edward@edward.com | ------ |

I have tried this, but dont know where the problem is:

```
def unificate (df):
for i in df:
    for x in df:
        if i['Email'] == x['Email']:
            i['Sales'] =+ x['Sales']
            ID = x['ID']
            index = df[df['ID'] == ID].index
            df.drop(index, inplace = True)
            return df
```

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Group by your email. Then sum your sales within groups. Your "ID" is created separately (which seems erroneous) so renumber using reset_index. Join the rest of your columns, you will need some separate reduction method (first, last, etc).

Comment: As to your code, `i` and `x` are going across column names rather than rows. If you want to iterate over rows, use `iterrows()`. Also, your `index = df[df['ID'] == ID].index` line, along with `df.drop(index, inplace=True)` would drop all IDs matching that number.

Answer (score 0):

I got it:

```
def groupby_sum(df, group_vars, agg_var='Total', sort_var='Total'):
'''
Return: a Pandas dataframe object where rows have been gruped by a given group of columns (categorical variables). 
        The resulting dataframe will be sorted descending from highest to lowest amount of deaths and the index column will be reset.
Input parameters:
    - df -> Pandas dataframe object: a dataframe with categorical variables and an aggregation variable.
    - group_vars -> list object: a list of values with the name of a group of categorical variables (e.g.: ['Sexo', 'Edad']).
    - agg_var -> string: a string with the name of the variable to be aggregated. In this case the variable 'Total' (number of deaths) is set as default.
    - sort_var -> string: a string with the name of the variable to sort the dataframe by. In this case the variable 'Total' (number of deaths) is set as default.
'''
df = df.groupby(group_vars, as_index=False).agg({agg_var:'sum'})
df = df.sort_values(by=sort_var, ascending=False)
return df.reset_index(drop=True)
```